# WS eb init missing equal-sign error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I ran and configure the key and the rest with `aws configure`

But when I run `eb init` I got the error

> ERROR: 'init/20160618/us-west-2/elasticbeanstalk/aws4_request' not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=eb init/20160618/us-west-2/elasticbeanstalk/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date, Signature=95e3...56e4'.

`Awsebcli` and `Python` should be set up correctly with version `EB CLI 3.7.6 (Python 2.7.1)`. Can someone help me figure out why?

Comment: instead of `ebinit` use your `accessKeyID` in Credential part in authorization header

Answer (score 6):

You have to remove or edit the file **config** on the occult directory named .aws, this directory usually is in C:/User/{Your user}/.aws or unix /User/{Your user}/.aws

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with the same error message, I solved the issue by adding "aws_access_key_id" and "aws_access_key_id" inside both "config" and "credentials" files inside ~/.aws/ directory.