# AWS eb init not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-5, web-deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was trying to set up a basic rails app and deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk. I ran eb init, picked my region and it asked for `(aws-access-id):` and `(aws-secret-key):`. For what ever reason it wasn't accepting my credentials and without realizing it at one point I had accidentally ran a command `eb --version` in the `(aws-access-id):` line. Now I can't get past choosing my region. I get

`ERROR: ServiceError - '--version/20190924/us-west-2/elasticbeanstalk/aws4_request' not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=eb --version/20190924/us-west-2/elasticbeanstalk/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=afc27125738fef1062fc8565e130ced6e0f7b2c343c2e28456d7693c8f396c92'.`

I have been looking for a solution for countless hours now and can't find anything. I tried deleting .elasticbeanstalk file(some had mentioned), uninstalling it altogether, aws configure and put in the proper credentials, followed other stackoverflow questions. Nothing seems to work and the error will not go away. Tried looking up how to reset the headers. Not sure why this was saved in the first place. I feel it should have just given me wrong credentials if anything.

[WS eb init missing equal-sign error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902100/ws-eb-init-missing-equal-sign-error)

I am on a mac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, finally figured it out thanks to the link in my question to another similar stack overflow question. What I did was cd to my root directory where I finally did `$ ls -a` to see hidden files and saw `.aws`. I `$ cd .aws` and then ran `$ open config`. It open this

```
aws_access_key_id = eb --version
aws_secret_access_key = ENTER_SECRET_HERE

[default]
output = json
region = 3
```

Changed the key_id and access_key and it worked! Hope it helps out someone else before going insane.

Answer (score 0):

in order to find the problem I used the cmd

```
eb init --verbose --debug
```

which included the output "...not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header..."

I then googled that and was lead to your post.   thanks!