# AWS 'eb init' not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) Bitbucket pipelines

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am setting up Bitbucket pipeline for a Wordpress deployment on Elastic Beanstalk.

This error message pops up in line `eb init --region AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --platform php-5.5` :

`ERROR: ServiceError - '/20200712/$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION/elasticbeanstalk/aws4_request' not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID/20200712/$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION/elasticbeanstalk/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=3d7fef....8383d5'.`

Other relevant questions and why it doesn't solve my problem :

- [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902100/ws-eb-init-missing-equal-sign-error) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58080154/aws-eb-init-not-a-valid-key-value-pair-missing-equal-sign/58080703#58080703) : Don't have /.aws/config in Bitbucket environment
- [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692554/how-to-use-eb-init-without-manual-instructions) : Error message mentioned above

The Bitbucket pipeline till now :

```
image: tyrellsys/aws-ebcli

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          script:
            - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
            - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
            - export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
            - export APPLICATION_NAME=$APPLICATION_NAME
            - export ENVIRONMENT_NAME=$ENVIRONMENT_NAME
            - eb init --region ap-southeast-1 --platform php-5.5
            - eb deploy wordpress-beanstalk
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS eb init not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58080154/aws-eb-init-not-a-valid-key-value-pair-missing-equal-sign)

Comment: This link 2 in my question. No, it doesn't

Comment: Are you sure that  the `$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and other variables are correct? No extra characters or missing any? Also what version of ebawscli do you use? I ask because platform `php-5.5` is deprecated.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for the hint. I replaced all the environment variables and the error went away. 

However, stuck with this new error : 


InvalidParameterValueError: No Application Version named 'app-eb0c-200713_022145' found.

Comment: You can go to EB  console and check if it exists or not. Maybe you need to recreate it? Btw, if you don't mind I would like to provide the answer for the posted issue (i.e. key=value pair) for future reference.

Comment: The same command, 'eb deploy $ENVIRONMENT_NAME' works from my local machine which is Ubuntu 18.04 and creates new artifact in S3 + deploys with the new application version name. I can deploy a previous application version with no issue in Bitbucket pipelines. But that replaces the old artifact in S3 which I need to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was related to **incorrectly set** `$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`.

Fixing the values was the solution to the reported issue with `key=value pair (missing equal-sign)`.